# Can't get rid of download file dialog on subsequent requests

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I use following code to download the result from a mysql query to a excel file.

```
function Button14Click($sender, $params)
{
  IF ($this->ReadTheDates($Date1,$Date2))
  {
    mysql_connect('myServer','user','password');
    mysql_select_db('myDatabase');
    $SQLstr2 = $this->GetMySQL();
    $result = mysql_query($SQLstr2);
    // filename for download
    $filename = "File " .$Date1.'  '.$Date2. ".xls";
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
    $flag = false;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
      if(!$flag)
      { // display field/column names as first row
        echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
        $flag = true;
      }
      array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
      echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
    }
    exit();
  }
```

After setting the Header to download of the data via a file, e.g header("content disp ...) this header remains active until I manually reload the page. If I in a following command for example create and run a new query not for download I still get the download dialog with the file I just downloaded!

How do I reset, or remove, the header to the state it had before I changed it with the command header(...) as described above, and go back to a "normal" execution so to speak?

I have tried with header_remove() and with several methods of reloading the page from the code without success.

Comment: um what? you send a header so the browser is expecting a file to download - so what is it you want to do>

Comment: also its not an excel file, naming a file *.xls does change the format of the data. its simply tab delimited, may as well create a csv - much better compatibility

Comment: I have ediited my question and tried to be more specific on my problem and question. Yes I'm aware of that it not become an excelfile only by naming it .xls, it is a way to get Windows to open it with Excel without to many questions to the user.

Comment: still makes little sense to me, you call the function you get the header, untill a new request there cant be another,

Comment: OK, for example I have two buttons. The first is calling a function that make a query and show the result in a grid. The second calls another function that make another query and create a download file. If I use button number 2 and download my file and then press button 1 I still get the download dialouge but no presentation in the grid. After a manual refresh of the page it works again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem by moving the "Excel"-export to a new window to which I passed my parameters with $_SESSION vector. See example below.
Now it works.

```
function Button14Click($sender, $params)
{
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['datt1'] =       $this->JTDatePicker1->Date;
  $_SESSION['datt2'] =       $this->JTDatePicker2->Date;
  $_SESSION['PilotIdx'] =    $this->JTLookupComboBox1->getSelectedValue();
  $_SESSION['FlygplanIdx'] = $this->JTLookupComboBox4->getSelectedValue();
  $_SESSION['KlubbIdx'] =    $this->JTLookupComboBox2->getSelectedValue();
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      myWindow = window.open("ExcelDownloadForm.php");
    </script>
  <?php
}
```